# how to make .sis go online

Tags: qt, connection, symbian

I'm trying to write a program with qt for my symbian phone nokia 5800. In my program, i'm trying to go online and save the .html file of a desired website. My program works fine with qt device simulator but when i build it and send to my phone it doesn't work. I guess phone doesn't go online because it doesn't ask me to choose a connection. You guys have any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, first ask her to start up her PC. Then it might be a good idea to open up a web browser and enter an address to the URL bar. Voilá!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution by looking at the sample codes of qt.

Try this:

https://projects.forum.nokia.com/CartoonReader/files/releases/QtWebKit_CartoonReader_Example_v1_2_en.zip